# Error in stl_vector when updating to xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c++, xcode4.2

I'm trying to update an app of mine to Xcode 4.2, and now it's giving me a bunch of errors in stl_vector.h, a library that is part of the built in libraries. Here is a picture of the error:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure out how to fix this. I don't have permission to even edit the function that is throwing errors since it is built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight guess, since you don't give us enough information, but if `OBJMaterial` etc are Objective-C classes, you can't pass them by value, i.e. you always work with pointers.

Comment: +1 This ended up being the culprit. Took a few hours, but I got everything switched around to pointers and now it works fine. Thanks.